# How to avoid the comma in json object?

Tags: c#, java, json

I am writing an application to get the json object from server.
for example:

```
{"23423423", [abc, 2009-10-12, hello]}
```

My problem is:
if abc is a string that contains comma, then how can I parse the content in square brackets?
normally it should be three items in the square brackets. But if abc contains a comma, then I will get four items, which is not right.
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
List list = new ArrayList(); 
list.add("abc"); 
list.add("2009-10"); 
obj.put("234234", list.toString());// don't use toString();
```

Finally I solve it, I should not use the list.toString(), otherwise the whole list will be converted to a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `abc` is a string, then it should be coming from the server quoted, as `"abc"`. If it isn't, then whatever created the JSON is doing it wrong.

Comment: +1. Exactly. And if it's quoted, a decent JSON parser should handle it just fine.

Comment: it's a string but after I put it into a list, the quoted lost

Comment: I use following code: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); List list = new ArrayList();  list.add("abc"); list.add("2009-10"); obj.put("234234", list.toString()); and finally I got the result above.

Answer (score 1):

A decent JSON parser handles that. Why not just use one of the existing C# JSON parsers out there, such as [JSONSharp](http://code.google.com/p/jsonsharp/)?